# How to avoid cluttering the names of Python functions that differ in their input argument types?

Tags: python, function, overloading, variable-names

Suppose you have functions `f1: A1 ->B, f2: A2->B, …`.   Julia has function overloading, so you could define them all as `f`, and the type `A1, A2, …` will determine which one gets applied.  When encountering this situation in Python, is there any way to avoid having to construct different functions with different names, and as a result probably including some description of input arguments in function names (something like `B_from_A1`,  `B_from_A2` , etc.), thereby cluttering the function names?

Answer (score 0):

Python has a few different ways that you can encapsulate different amounts of arguments into a single function definition.

### Arbitrary Arguments:

```
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

`args` and `kwargs` will be available inside the function. `args` will be a `tuple` containing positional arguments in the same order that they are passed into the function. `kwargs` will be a `dict` whose `key:value` mappings will correspond to the `name=value` keyword arguments passed to the function.

Note: the function can be called without passing anything, in which case both of these structures would be empty.

As well, other parameters can be defined in the function definition, and Python will always pass values for these arguments before the "catch-all" `*args` and `**kwargs`.

Example:

```
def foo(a, b, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

`a` and `b` are now required, and anything passed beyond them will be given to `*args` and `**kwargs`.

### Default Arguments:

Arguments can also be given default values such that you are no longer required to pass a value into them in order to call the function.

```
def foo(a='test', b='test2')
    ...
```

Using this pattern, you can simply call `foo` like so:

`>>> foo()`

and the function will receive the default values for `a` and `b`.

This pattern can be mixed with the previous one to create rather robust function definitions:

```
def foo(a, b, c='test', *args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

`a` and `b` are required, `c` has a default value and is therefore optional, any other positional parameters will be placed into `args` and any other keyword parameters will be placed into `kwargs`.

Python also has the ability to specify parameters as keyword-only or positional-only, to add even more specificity using `/` and `*`, respectively:

```
def foo(positional_1, positional_2, /, standard_1, standard_2, *, keyword_1, keyword_2):
    ...
```

You can read even more about the process at:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions